# Linux Mint is showing month name in a language other than English

Tags: linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint installation with English language interface, but the month name in the console is in Hebrew. How do I make it show the month name in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem!

Solution:

1. go to System->Language
2. remove Hebrew language (i make it, but may be it's not necessary, try before step 3 & 4)
3. select English, United Stated and click Apply System-Wide
4. logout and login.